# C++ program checking for tag validity

Tags: c++, debugging, tokenize

I'm a beginner in C++ and was trying to make the checks work as they are suppose to. But it's returning true for nearly every test. It's only suppose to return true in this case:

```
<red> Red blank <dim> I'm now dim and red. </dim> </red>
```

But this as well returns true when it's now:

```
<red> Blah I'm red.<dim> Im dim now </red> </dim>
```

or this :

```
 <red> blah <im dim now
```

So I'm wondering if there's something I'm overlooking in my code.

```
bool is_well_formed(ifstream& ifs, string& error_msg) {

string fname,line;
Token tok;
Lexer lexer;
tags.insert("blue");
tags.insert("red");
tags.insert("cyan");
tags.insert("white");
tags.insert("yellow");
tags.insert("magenta");
tags.insert("dim");
tags.insert("underline");
tags.insert("bold");

stack<string> tagstack;
while (getline(ifs, fname)) { 
    // tries to open the file whose name is in string fname

    if (ifs.fail()) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << fname << endl;
        ifs.clear();
    } else {
        while (getline(ifs, line)) {
            lexer.set_input(line);
            while (lexer.has_more_token()) {
                tok = lexer.next_token();
                string tmpTok = tok.value;
                switch (tok.type) {
                case TAG:

                    // If it has /, remove / from tmpTok
                if (tok.value[0] == '/') {
                    // If it's a closing t
                        tmpTok = tmpTok.substr(1,tmpTok.length()-1);
                    }
                    if(tags.find(tmpTok) == tags.end()) {
                    // Check whether the encountered tag is valid
                    error_return("Tag " + tmpTok + " is invalid!");
                    return false;
                     } else {
                     // Valid Tag encountered

                     tagstack.push(tmpTok);
                     // Check if the tags are formed properly
                            if (tmpTok.find('/')) {
                             // Remove / from tmpTok
                            string closingTag =  tmpTok;
                                string openingTag = tagstack.top();
                                tagstack.pop();
                    if(closingTag.compare(openingTag) != 0) {
                        error_return(closingTag+"doesn't match" +openingTag);
                        return false;
                      } //else 
                                  //  return true; // if the file is well formed
                 }/**else{
                    tagstack.push(tmpTok);
                 }*/
                     }// else end    

                    break;
               case IDENT:
                   // cout << "IDENT: " << tok.value << endl;
                    break; 
                case ERRTOK:
                    error_return("Syntax error on this line\n");
                    return false;
                    //cout << "Syntax error on this line\n";
                    break;
                case ENDTOK:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return true; // if the file is well-formed
 }
```

Comment: Your tag stack is too short-lived. You should declare it near the top of your function so that it can see more than one tag. There might be other problems but it's not really possible to find anything not too obvious without a full compilable text of the program.

Answer (score 1):

For something this simple (and this must be simple because this stands no chance of parsing real-world who-knows-what-you're-gonna-get-XML) A couple of things could be different but your immediate problem is straight forward:

Move the `stack<string> tagstack` declaration either outside the per-line loop, or better still, outside the entire processing loop. Where it sits now as soon you push a tag onto the stack and exit the scope of the `else{}` block where it is declared, that state is lost.

Your state machine could use some work for more robustness, but that is another issue, fix the scope of your tag-stack first.

You need to run this under a **debugger**, and you should get used to that because every professional C/C++ engineer I know spends half their productive life in one. It comes with the business. That being said, regarding always returning true, I'll proffer up these questions back to you, not to answer here, but to investigate, again, in a **debugger**

1. What happens if the lexer never returns a token type of TAG?
2. What happens if the lexer returns a token of type TAG, but it never starts with a '/'?
3. What happens if the lexer returns a token type of TAG, and it begins with a '/', but you then proceed to chop off the '/'?

In one place in your code it appears you're checking the first char of your token for a '/', while not two lines later you appear to be trying to throw out the beginning and ending element markers '<' and '>'. Specifically:

```
if (tok.value[0] == '/') {
   // If it's a closing t
   tmpTok = tmpTok.substr(1,tmpTok.length()-1);
}
```

These two lines of code are not congruent for a closing tag. First you check for a leading '/', indicating the <> are already stripped, the next line you proceed to strip the lead and tail char off the string, as if it *had* both <> still present. But what if they're NOT present (and they can't be, otherwise your check for '/' would have been false. Do you see it now? You're slicing off the '/'. Is that important? well. look further down the code, we find:

```
if (tmpTok.find('/')) {
   // Remove / from tmpTok
   string closingTag =  tmpTok;
   string openingTag = tagstack.top();
   tagstack.pop();
   if(closingTag.compare(openingTag) != 0) {
      error_return(closingTag+"doesn't match" +openingTag);
      return false;
   } //else
}
```

**NONE of the code inside the check for '/' is going to execute since you just cut it off.** Therefore you'll go through your whole file adding token after token thinking they're all entry tokens, then run out of lines, and presto, return true. In reality **if there is anything LEFT on the tagstack at file end there MUST be a misbalance, and hence an error**. Put *that* conditional check as part of your overall eval and I guarantee you'll start seeing false filtering out of this.

Now get thee to a **debugger**. I managed to find all of this just perusing the code. Imagine the things you'll see while actually *running* it line-by-line in a debugger where you can see the changes in real-time.

Comment: I've changed it to be outside the entire loop but it still returns everything as true.